# MDM & "Work Profile" Implications on Android 14

Tags: privacy, android

What are the privacy implications of using an MDM "work profile" on your own Android 14 device? First, an MDM app such as MaaS360 must create the work profile while running in the personal profile. During this phase, could the app apply invasive device policies without informing the user (online searches, which may not apply to newer versions of Android, suggest MDM apps run with elevated permissions)? While there is a firewall between the personal and work profiles, MDM still mandates some device-level policies such as password requirements and so forth. Some policies can [completely invade your privacy](https://blog.cdemi.io/never-accept-an-mdm-policy-on-your-personal-phone/), for example: installing root SSL certificates or mandating VPNs. Is it possible for my personal privacy to be violated - with or without my knowledge - while using Android's work profiles?

Comment: You might also be interested about the discussion/debate on the comment thread of that article.

Comment: Yes it is interesting but not authoritative.

Comment: Welcome to the community. Are you referring to InTune specifically or MDM in general?

Comment: Thanks! MDM in general.